# Data Factory Data Copy from REST to Table Storage - PartitionKey null [object/array]

Tags: json, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

Good day,

We are importing the following JSON format via COPY DATA (REST TO TABLE STORAGE) in Data Factory v2:

```
[  
   {  
      "ERROR":false,
      "USERNAME":"DUMMY"
   },
   [  
      {  
         "A":1,
         "B":2,
         "C":3
      },
      {  
         "A":1,
         "B":0,
         "C":3
      }
   ]
]
```

Partition key value: `USE SOURCE COLUMN`

Partition key column: `C`

Mapping is properly set for `A B and C`. ERROR and USERNAME are -- Not Included --.

Gives the following error in debug:

> "errorCode": "2200", "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side.
>   ErrorCode=UserErrorAzureTableKeyColumnWithNullValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
>   'C' contains 'NULL' value thus cannot be used as 'PartitionKey' for
>   Azure Table.

I understand why the error happens, the COPY DATA tool tries to create three rows:

1.Fist row is based on ERROR and USERNAME. This row has indeed value null for C

2.Second row is based on A, B and C. This row is correct as there are no null values for C.

3.Third row is based on A, B and C. This row is correct as there are no null values for C.

Fault tolerance is on: Skip incompatible rows, but does not solve the problem.

We know above because it works with default Partition Key value:

[Screenshot two rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5BCO.png)

We can't change the format of the input. What can we do in Data Factory to solve this issue? How can we disregard first object with ERROR and USER, or how can we skip rows with Partition Key if null?

Is this something that can handled with "Dynamic Content" code?

Comment: Hi,any updates now?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Sinbad. Based on my test,there is no direct way to skip the specific rows in the `REST-TableStorage` copy activity.

My idea is that you could use [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) to process your rest api data first.

Please refer to the below steps:

1.Create [Http Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook) in Azure Funtion, access your rest api and get the data.

2.In that Azure Function,loop the data and remove the "`ERROR"` and `"USERNAME"` row to return the array which only contains `"A" "B" "C"`.

3.Execute the function in azure data factory with Azure Function activity ,then link with copy activity.

[image]

There will be no more incompatible rows.